# Scipy fails to minimize cost function

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, statistics

Currently I'm learning from Andrew Ng course on Coursera called "Machine Learning". In exercise 5, we built a model that can predict digits, trained by the MNIST dataset. This task was completed successfully in Matlab by me, but I wanted to migrate that code to Python, just to see how different things are and maybe continue to play around with the model.

I managed to implement the cost function and the back propagation algorithm correctly. I know that because I compared the metrics with my working model in Matlab and it emits the same numbers.

Now, because in the course we train the model using fmincg, I tried to do the same using Scipy fmin_cg
function.

My problem is, the cost function takes extra small steps and fails to converge.
Here is my code for the network:

```
import numpy as np
import utils
import scipy.optimize as op

class Network:
    def __init__(self, layers):
        self.layers = layers
        self.weights = self.generate_params()

    # Function for generating theta multidimensional matrix
    def generate_params(self):
        theta = []
        epsilon = 0.12
        for i in range(len(self.layers) - 1):
            current_layer_units = self.layers[i]
            next_layer_units = self.layers[i + 1]
            theta_i = np.multiply(
                np.random.rand(next_layer_units, current_layer_units + 1),
                2 * epsilon - epsilon
            )
            
            # Appending the params to the theta matrix
            theta.append(theta_i)
        
        return theta

    # Function to append bias row/column to matrix X
    def append_bias(self, X, d):
        m = X.shape[0]
        n = 1 if len(X.shape) == 1 else X.shape[1]

        if (d == 'column'):
            ones = np.ones((m, n + 1))
            ones[:, 1:] = X.reshape((m, n))
        elif (d == 'row'):
            ones = np.ones((m + 1, n))
            ones[1:, :] = X.reshape((m, n))

        return ones 
        
    # Function for computing the gradient for 1 training example
    def back_prop(self, y, feed, theta):
        activations = feed["activations"]
        weighted_layers = feed["weighted_layers"]
        
        delta_output = activations[-1] - y.reshape(len(y), 1)
        current_delta = delta_output
        
        # Initializing gradients
        gradients = []
        for i, theta_i in enumerate(theta):
            gradients.append(np.zeros(theta_i.shape))
            
        # Peforming delta calculations.
        # Here, we continue to propagate the delta values backwards
        # until we arrive to the second layer.
        for i in reversed(range(len(theta))):
            theta_i = theta[i]
            if (i > 0):
                i_weighted_inputs = self.append_bias(weighted_layers[i - 1], 'row')
                t_theta_i = np.transpose(theta_i)
                delta_i = np.multiply(np.dot(t_theta_i, current_delta), utils.sigmoidGradient(i_weighted_inputs))
                delta_i = delta_i[1:]
                
                gradients[i] = current_delta * np.transpose(activations[i])
                
                # Setting current delta for the next layer
                current_delta = delta_i
            else:
                gradients[i] = current_delta * np.transpose(activations[i])

        return gradients
        
    # Function for computing the cost and the derivatives
    def compute_cost(self, theta, X, y, r12n = 0):
        m = len(X)
        num_labels = self.layers[-1]

        costs = np.zeros(m)

        # Initializing gradients
        gradients = []
        for i, theta_i in enumerate(theta):
            gradients.append(np.zeros(theta_i.shape))
            
        # Iterating over the training set
        for i in range(m):
            inputs = X[i]
            observed = utils.create_output_vector(y[i], num_labels)
            feed = self.feed_forward(inputs)
            predicted = feed["activations"][-1]
            
            total_cost = 0
            for k, o in enumerate(observed):
                if (o == 1):
                    total_cost += np.log(predicted[k])
                else:
                    total_cost += np.log(1 - predicted[k])

            cost = -1 * total_cost

            # Storing the cost for the i-th training example
            costs[i] = cost
            
            # Calculating the gradient for this training example
            # using back propagation algorithm
            gradients_i = self.back_prop(observed, feed, theta)
            
            for i, gradient in enumerate(gradients_i):
                gradients[i] += gradient


        # Calculating the avg regularization term for the cost
        sum_of_theta = 0
        for i, theta_i in enumerate(theta):
            squared_theta = np.power(theta_i[:, 1:], 2)
            sum_of_theta += np.sum(squared_theta)

        r12n_avg = r12n * sum_of_theta / (2 * m)
        total_cost = np.sum(costs) / m + r12n_avg

        # Applying regularization terms to the gradients
        for i, theta_i in enumerate(theta):
            lambda_i = np.copy(theta_i)
            lambda_i[:, 0] = 0
            lambda_i = np.multiply((r12n / m), lambda_i)
            
            # Adding the r12n matrix to the gradient
            gradients[i] = gradients[i] / m + lambda_i

        return total_cost, gradients
    
    # Function for training the neural network using conjugate gradient algorithm
    def train_cg(self, X, y, r12n = 0, iterations = 50):
        weights = self.weights

        def Cost(theta, X, y):
            theta = utils.roll_theta(theta, self.layers)
            cost, _ = self.compute_cost(theta, X, y, r12n)
            print(cost);
            return cost
            
        def Gradient(theta, X, y):
            theta = utils.roll_theta(theta, self.layers)
            _, gradient = self.compute_cost(theta, X, y, r12n)
            return utils.unroll_theta(gradient)
        
        unrolled_theta = utils.unroll_theta(weights)
        result = op.fmin_cg(f = Cost,
                             x0 = unrolled_theta,
                             args=(X, y),
                             fprime=Gradient,
                             maxiter = iterations)
        
        self.weights = utils.roll_theta(result, self.layers)
        
    # Function for feeding forward the network 
    def feed_forward(self, X):
        # Useful variables
        activations = []
        weighted_layers = []
        weights = self.weights

        currentActivations = self.append_bias(X, 'row')
        activations.append(currentActivations)

        for i in range(len(self.layers) - 1):
            layer_weights = weights[i]
            weighted_inputs = np.dot(layer_weights, currentActivations)
            
            # Storing the weighted inputs
            weighted_layers.append(weighted_inputs)

            activation_nodes = []
            # If the next layer is not the output layer, we'd like to add a bias unit to it
            # (Excluding the input and the output layer)
            if (i < len(self.layers) - 2):
                activation_nodes = self.append_bias(utils.sigmoid(weighted_inputs), 'row')
            else:
                activation_nodes = utils.sigmoid(weighted_inputs)
            
            # Appending the layer of nodes to the activations array
            activations.append(activation_nodes)
            currentActivations = activation_nodes
        data = {
            "activations": activations,
            "weighted_layers": weighted_layers
        }
        return data

    def predict(self, X):
        data = self.feed_forward(X)
        output = data["activations"][-1]
        
        # Finding the max index in the output layer
        return np.argmax(output, axis=0)
```

Here is the invocation of the code:

```
import numpy as np
from network import Network

# %% Load data
X = np.genfromtxt('data/mnist_data.csv', delimiter=',')
y = np.genfromtxt('data/mnist_outputs.csv', delimiter=',').astype(int)

# %% Create network
num_labels = 10

input_layer = 400
hidden_layer = 25
output_layer = num_labels
layers = [input_layer, hidden_layer, output_layer]

# Create a new neural network
network = Network(layers)

# %% Train the network and save the weights
network.train_cg(X, y, r12n = 1, iterations = 20)
```

This is what the code emits after each iteration:

```
15.441233231650283
15.441116436313076
15.441192262452514
15.44122384651483
15.441231216030646
15.441232804294314
15.441233141284435
15.44123321255294
15.441233227614855
```

As you can see, the changes to the cost are very small.

I checked for the shapes of the vectors and gradient and they both seem fine, just like in my Matlab implementation. I'm not sure what I do wrong here.

If you guys could help me, that'd be great :)

Comment: That's way too long of a question!  I have a 30 second attention span.